# Another Holiday Rebus

Tags: rebus, seasonal

What's the meaning of *this* rebus? Another very good message to share.
Slightly harder this time!

[image]

Comment: I'd like to dis that dis: dis-miss the "s".

Comment: Should probably by "l+[fire.png]-h" instead of "[fire.png]-h+l", I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A [little] bit(-e) of [light] dispel(-l)s a (lot*) of darkness